# Priority queue with custom comparator segmentation fault when pushing second time

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, priority-queue, comparator

I'm using a `priority_queue`, this is the code:

```
typedef vector<int> state;
typedef bool (*comp)(const state&, const state&);
typedef priority_queue<state, vector<state>, comp> prioq;

prioq prio;
```

I'm using a custom comparator, that is defined here:

```
bool comparator (const state& a , const state& b) {
    return a[0] < b[0];
}
```

I can push the first state, but when I try to push the second, I get a segmentation fault: 11.

I don't know if the comparator is right, I don't know really much how to create a custom comparator. I'm trying to order the `priority_queue` by the first number of each state.

Comment: storing vectors in a priority queue is not the best idea

Comment: I need to store unidimensional or multidimensional vectors. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`prioq prio;` constructs a priority queue with a default-constructed comparator (of type `comp` in your case). This means that the internally stored pointer to a comparing function is actually initialized with zero. A comparator (if a default constructed one is not enough) can be initialized to a value passed as a constructor's argument:

```
prioq prio(&comparator);
//         ~~~~~~~~~~^
```

Comment: I receive this 2 errors:

/puzzle.cpp:17:13: error: use of undeclared identifier 'comparator'; did you mean 'operator'?
prioq prio(&comparator);
            ^~~~~~~~~~
            operator


./puzzle.cpp:17:23: error: expected a type
prioq prio(&comparator);

Comment: @elena.bdc put the declaration of `comparator` before you refer to this name